# Validating X12 message in logic apps

Tags: azure-logic-apps, x12

I have an EDI message in a logic app taken from a blob container. I need to validate the message and then encode it using x12 for sending purposes. I've seen how to encode the message using the encode shape, but how I just validate it.

Best Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use "[XML Validation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-enterprise-integration-xml-validation)" action in your logic app to validate it. Before that you need to [add schemas](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-enterprise-integration-schemas#edit-schemas) in your integration account.

Comment: I did it using the decode shape from x12, but it also worked as you explained